# Define custom syntax "until" in C

Tags: c, syntax, macros, preprocessor-directive

I expect I can do something like this:

```
int i = 0;
until (i == 2){
  printf("yes\n");
  i++;
}
```

Without telling detail about what `until` does, I'm sure reader know what is the algorithm from code above. Yes I know I can just use `while(!condition){}`.

The output will be:

```
yes
yes
```

So is it possible that I can achieve my goal?

I feel macro able to do this with `define` or something else. But I'm lack of knowledge about preprocessing directive syntax in C

```
#define until <what should I fill here>
```

Edit:
Many people triggered from what am I doing. I'm sorry for if I bother you guys. Don't worry, this syntax is just for my self only. So I hope I don't bother code reader who accidentally read my code or C priest.

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that ? IMHO it will just confuse people who read you code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `define` for that. See the following example for the macro definition

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define until(x) while(!(x))

int main() {
   int i = 0;
   until (i == 2){
     printf("iteration %d\n", i);
     i++;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

If you run it, the output would be

```
iteration 0
iteration 1
```

Answer (score 10):

First of all, and I can't stress this enough: making your own secret, private language using function-like macros is a cardinal sin in C. It is perhaps the worst thing you can ever do.

Why? Because other people reading your code are expected to know C. They are however not expected to know your secret private macro language. Furthermore, they have absolutely no interest in learning your secret private macro language.

So please never do things like this in real programs.

---

That being said, you pretty much already answered the question yourself:

```
#define until(condition) while(!(condition))
```

Note that `condition`, being a function-like macro parameter, should be placed inside a parenthesis. This prevents accidental operator precedence bugs. For example if the caller passes `until(i + 1)` then you want it to loop `while(!(i+1))` and *not* `while(!i + 1)`.

Comment: I suggest using `__VA_ARG__` in case someone decides to put a comma operator `,` into the conditions. It happen occasionally.  `#define until(...) while(!(__VA_ARGS__))`

Comment: @Lundin, BITD, I dealt with a large code base that used `#define begin { int i;` and used `while (cond) begin ... f(i); ... }`  --> unmatched `{}`, mysterious `i`s and unable to auto-format.  Yuck.

Comment: @tstanisl If so, they are better off with a compiler error than silent acceptance.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Sounds like some grumpy Pascal programmer was in charge of the code base at some point :)

Comment: I can easily imagine someone writing `until(c = getchar(), c == EOF) { ... }`.

Comment: @tstanisl C is known for its heavy use of karma. If you write C code like that, the universe will find ways to punish you for it.

Answer (score 6):

From *Expert C Programming*:

> Macro use is best confined to naming literal constants,
> shorthand for a few well-chosen constructs. Define the macro name all
> in capitals so that, in use, it's instantly clear it's not a function
> call. Shun any use of the C preprocessor that modifies the underlying
> language so that it's no longer C.

*Re: "I'm sure reader know what is the algorithm from code above."*

---

No, it would confuse one even more as the keyword `until` is not part of the `C` language. It doesn't take much to type a few extra characters.

That being said, you could do:

```
#define until(condition) while(!(condition))
```

Compile your program with:

```
gcc -E -nostdinc main.c
```

to see what changes the preprocessor made.

But it would still be an abomination, and not something one would condone.

Answer (score 4):

**Using `until` is useful in select cases.**

Sometimes an algorithm or software contract uses *until* in its definition, so it is good to see that match in code.

Yet re-writing language semantics adds confusion and maintenance costs.

Consider a *comment* when *until* is needed.

```
int i = 0;

// until (i == 2) {
while (i != 2) {
  printf("yes\n");
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would do this, `until` is a mostly abandoned keyword for a reason. But this should work:

```
#define until(cond) while (!(cond))
```

Comment: In your answer, you wrote: `"until is a mostly abandoned keyword`" -- In my opinion, this formulation is misleading. The token `until` is not a [keyword in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I meant in programming languages in general.

Comment: You may want to [edit] your answer to clarify this.